# how to add the new cell in table view from app in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c

how to add the new cell in tableview  after running the program. that  mean from the app
i want to add the new cell for new entity like adding the new contact name in table view.

Answer (score 3):

A proper answer to this would be very long.  This topic is covered comprehensively in the official documentation:

- [Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html)

You really need to go through and learn the basics, and come back here with specific questions you may have.  Apple provide loads of tutorials, sample code, guides and references.  Have fun!